# What is the best way to generate a unique unsigned integer from a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, int, theory

I don't need code (you can provide examples in code if you wish) but I would like the theory.

Let's pretend I have the following function:

```
UINT GenerateID(const char * string);
```

I would like the function's result to look completely random.  I understand that it is impossible to be unique, but that is the best way I could explain my desire.

```
GenerateID("123"); //Could result in 999
GenerateID("123"); //Must also result in 999
GenerateID("124"); //Should result in something completely different
```

When attempting this myself, the results always have roughly the same amount of digits.

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for a hash function. A hash function takes an input of arbitrary length and converts it to a unique number (often hexadecimal).

Check this page out for an example of how the SHA-1 hash works: http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into std::hash ?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done. Suppose for the sake of argument that your `int` is 32 bit. A text string will be made out of `' '`, `a-zA-Z` and `0-9` and a half dozen punctuation characters, for a total of around 1 + 2*26 + 10 + 6 =  69 characters. With strings of 6 characters you already have more possible strings than integer values (log(2^32)/log(69) = 5.23). Use `long long` of 64 bits, and you have run out at 11 characters.

As the other answers say, you could use a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) (there are lots floating around), which will map the strings to integers and (hopefully) spread them equally over the selected range of integers.

There are techniques to construct *perfect hash functions*, that for a *fixed* set of strings cook up a function and a not-too-large range that guarantees no collisions (no two strings give the same integer).

If this is used in a program, and the strings can be controlled by an attacker, you are subject to [algorithmic complexity attacks](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~scrosby/hash/CrosbyWallach_UsenixSec2003.pdf) (an attacker can swamp you with strings that collide).